# Can I replace digits found via regex by applying mathematical operations?

Tags: regex, replace, find, editor

I use Perl regex in UltraEdit to find and replace text with no problem. But lately, I've needed a lot to replace digits (numbers) I find with another number generated from the found number by applying mathematical operations.
For example, I search for a three digits number `\d\d\d`, let's say I found `264`. What I need is to replace the found number with another number by adding, for example, 5, then it should be replaced with `269`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Questions about how to use your editor belong on Super User.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, you can use the `/e` ("evaluate") modifier:

```
s/(\d\d\d)/$1+5/e
```

I'm not sure about its availability in UltraEdit, though.

Comment: I used Find: `(\d\d\d)` and Replaced with: `s/(\d\d\d)/$1+5/e`. But the result was `s/(ddd)/264+5/e`, not `269`.

Comment: @user3503851 , `s///` is Perl operator. Makes no sense to use it as the replacement expression. Only `$1+5` is the replacement expression. But of course, there's no equivalent to `e` in UE.

Answer (score 1):

UltraEdit does not have give the capability to execute code (of any kind) to generate the replacement value.

You could easily use `perl` to do the task, though.

```
perl -i.bak -e"s/(\d\d\d)/$1+5/eg" file
```

Or if you want to use wildcards,

```
perl -MFile::DosGlob=glob -i.bak -e"BEGIN { @ARGV = map glob($_), @ARGV } s/(\d\d\d)/$1+5/eg" *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

UltraEdit has the capability to execute code as UltraEdit has a scripting support since version 13.00 which uses the JavaScript core engine.

Here is an UltraEdit script for searching in a file for all numbers with exactly 3 digits and increase all found numbers by a value of 5.

```
if (UltraEdit.document.length > 0)  // Is any file opened?
{
   // Define environment for this script.
   UltraEdit.insertMode();
   UltraEdit.columnModeOff();
   // Move caret to top of the active file.
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.top();
   // Define the parameters for the Perl regular expression find.
   UltraEdit.perlReOn();
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.mode=0;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchCase=true;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchWord=false;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.regExp=true;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchDown=true;
   if (typeof(UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchInColumn) == "boolean")
   {
      UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchInColumn=false;
   }
   // Search in a loop for numbers with exactly 3 digits, convert each
   // found number as string selected in the active file to a number,
   // increment the number by 5 and write the number converted back
   // to string over the found number string.
   while(UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.find("(?<!\\d)\\d{3}(?!\\d)"))
   {
      var nNumber = parseInt(UltraEdit.activeDocument.selection,10);
      nNumber += 5;
      UltraEdit.activeDocument.write(nNumber.toString(10));
   }
   // Move caret back to top of the file.
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.top();
}
```